# How to set the Publisher property in the Outlook COM add-ins?

Tags: c#, com, outlook, add-in, publisher

I develop the **Outlook COM Add-In** write in **C#** and use the **Installshield** for create the setup file.

And then I saw that the **Publisher** property in the **Outlook Options Add-Ins dialog** is **<[None]>**. I want to set that property and ask Google for resolve this problem but cannot do it.

Could you please give me some advice?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

To get the "Publisher" filled you need to sign your addin with a digital signature. You'll get in the value of the "publisher" field the name of the owner of the signing certificate (company name or your name).

Means, you need to order a code-signing certificate from some certification authority (like VeriSign, Comodo or  StartSSL) and then sign your addin with this certificate. To get the code signing certificate you'll need to prove your identity (that you are really you :), may take some time.

This is basically a security feature which allows users to know for sure who is is the author of the program.